# Using .append for several string items at a time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is probably a basic question for most of you but I can't find any specific info on by googling, nor in any of the previously asked questions:

I would like to know whether it is possible to append several items to a list already containing one item by using **.append** and then get the number output of all of them using `len()`. When I enter my code as follows:

```
bag.append('suit', 'shoes', 'socks')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

I have tried double parentheses as follows:

```
bag.append(('suit', 'shoes', 'socks))
```

but this results in `len(bag)` telling me that there are only 2 items in `bag` (i.e. the original one & `(suit, shoes, socks)`. The number aimed for is 4 (i.e. original item + suit + shoes + socks).

The only method I have used that has successfully accomplished this is as follows:

```
bag.append('suit')
bag.append('shoes')
bag.append('socks')
```

When running `len(bag)` on this, I get the correct output for the 4 items separately, i.e. **4** (original item **bag = [gloves]** + **'suit'** + **'shoes'** + **'socks'**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two lists together using the `+` operator

```
>>> l = ['hat', 'coat']
>>> x = l + ['suit', 'shoes', 'socks']
>>> x
['hat', 'coat', 'suit', 'shoes', 'socks']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess that was the obvious method I was missing. Appreciate it and accepted!

Comment: It's worth to mention that using in-place (augmented) addition would be a closer answer to the original question: `bag += ['suit', 'shoes', 'socks']`

Comment: OK, that works too, so 3 methods to achieve the same thing. Upvoted your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than `append`, `extend`:

```
bag.extend(['suit', 'shoes', 'socks'])
```

See e.g. [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Out of curiosity I did a performance test, and `extend` seems to be ever so slightly slower than `+`: http://pastebin.com/7eGDEcBb (should not be a concern in most applications, just FYI).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked too and gave me the exact result I needed as well. For this specific question though, I was trying to get the output using `.append`. Appreciate it though as I learnt something new (`.extend`). Tried to vote up your answer, but my reputation is too low at this point (need 15). Thanks again!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I get similar results (~8% faster for two 100-element lists). Interestingly the non in-place version (`l2 = l1 + ...`) is much faster (~40%).

Answer (score 2):

As the `TypeError` says, the [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method input is one item only, therefore any try to append more than one item on the same call will fail.

The reason `bag.append(('suit', 'shoes', 'socks))` didn't fail is since `('suit', 'shoes', 'socks)` is one item type [tuple](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html).

Use the `extend` method or the `+` operator as suggested here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it. Tried to upvote your answer, but don't have enough points yet. Thanks again.